# Size image proportionate to an image behind/beneath itself?

Tags: c#, xamarin

We have a simple page. It contains a `ListView` and a `Grid`. 
The `grid` contains two `Images`...

[image: current]

The two images individually are a grey rectangle and a white trapezoid.

[image: rectangle]

[image: trapezoid]

When we layer the rectangle over the trapezoid, the image sizing/scale (unsure which) isn't quite right. The desire is to layer it so the images line up like..

[image: correct]

The implementation now is two images added to a grid with a single row and a single column. The `RowDefinition` and `ColumnDefinition` are set to (one) 1 and auto. The two images are set to `CenterAndExpand` for both Horziontal and Vertical options.

**Is there a way to size our second image (grey rectangle) that is layered over our first image (white trapezoid) so that the rectangle is lined up with the trapezoid?** Current idea is to play around with the grid definitions and line it up using margins/padding but confident this solution won't translate onto various device display sizes.

As always thanks for reading. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions which can implement it . Since you had use Grid . You would better set the height of row as a static value so that the height of image will fit the row .

You could check the following code

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Black">

   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="50" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width=".30*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width=".30*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Source="pic1" Aspect="AspectFill"/> //white trapezoid
   <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="pic2" Aspect="AspectFill"/> //grey rectangle

</Grid>
```

For different device you just need to change the value of height (data binding).

[image]

Comment: In the case of the white trapezoid not consuming the entire height (padding on top/bottom) would the best practice solution be to use two additional rowdefinitions (three (3) total) like so - .1, .8, .1?

Comment: Of course you could change it as you want. My code is just for demo